# Keep font attributes consistent after draw function is called

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm having difficulty trying to maintain font size, position, and color after using the `draw()` with `attributes` function.

I have a `UIImage` and a `UITextField` where I'm trying to draw both of these into a single `UIImage`. So far, I've been able to achieve that but having trouble trying to keep the fonts attributes consistent after the `draw()` function has been called.

I firstly begin a new `imageContext` and draw the desired image into the `CGRect`. I then repeat this process using the `UITextField`.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(takenImage.size, true, takenImage.scale)

    let areaSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.takenImage.size.width, height: self.takenImage.size.height)
    takenImage.draw(in: areaSize)

    let imageViewSize = self.tempImageView.frame.size
    let multiWidth = areaSize.width / imageViewSize.width
    let multiHeight = areaSize.height / imageViewSize.height

    let textSize = CGRect(x: textOverlay.frame.origin.x * multiWidth, y: textOverlay.frame.origin.y * multiHeight, width: textOverlay.frame.size.width * multiWidth, height: textOverlay.frame.size.height * multiHeight)

    let ribbon = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    ribbon.setFill()
    UIRectFillUsingBlendMode(textSize, CGBlendMode.normal)

    let convertChatText: String = textOverlay.text!
    let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 17.0)!]

    convertChatText.draw(with: textSize, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attrs, context: nil)

    let outputImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

As you can see in the above code snippet, I convert my `UITextField.text` into a `String` and add `UIFont` attributes. Those attributes are then used as a parameter in the `draw` function.

Upon viewing my final image output, for some reason, the attributes specified aren't being applied to the text I'm unsure why?

I'm guessing that I'm doing *something* wrong, but can't quite figure out what?

**UPDATE**
I've uploaded images which further explain my issue, and can be viewed [here.](https://imgur.com/a/C0iBF)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the drawn text?

Comment: The text in the drawn image is showing black with a small font size. Wondering why the attributes aren't being applied. Sorry, should have emphasized. I'll upload an imgur now.

Comment: The only attribute you specify is the font. If you try different font sizes, do you see the change in the image?

Comment: If I change the font size to say, 27.0 the size increases slightly. Which makes me think it could somehow be down to scaling?

Comment: The `UITextView` font size is initially set in xcode editor with size = 17. When specifying font size in the `attrs` variable, its asking for a `CGPoint`... Is there some sort of conversion I need from point to CGPoint?

Comment: Your image link seems to be broken: I get 404 error

Answer (score 0):

Try using the attributes of textfield

```
    let font = textField.font
    let textColor = textField.textColor
    let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName: font!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textColor!]
```

Comment: What about specifying font size?

Comment: If you want to change the font size you can but my sample get the current font of your textfield. For example if the font size was 20, the size of the font parameter on attributes is also 20

Comment: I've tried your code. Color changes (great), but font size is still tiny. Hm

Comment: Ah, turns out it was a scaling issue. I changed the font size by: `let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 17.0 * multiHeight)`